# vba - Excel 2010. Local variable not initialized in my function

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my sub():

```
Sub SendEmail()

MyPrompt = "want to add a message?"
Mysubject = PopMessage(MyPrompt)

End Sub
```

Here is my function():

```
Public Function PopMessage(ByVal Mypromt As String) As String
'Open a existing userform with a MyPrompt MsgBox and catch user text

FormName = "UserForm1" ' choose here the desired UserForm
Dim Mytext As String
Mytext = ""

On Error Resume Next
MsgBox (MyPrompt) ' only for debuging
Response = MsgBox(Prompt:=MyPrompt, Buttons:=vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbYes Then
    If UserForm1 Is Nothing Then ' we want to check if userform exists
        MsgBox ("Le Formulaire n'existe pas")
        Exit Function
   End If
        Unload UserForm1 ' first we clear the userform
        UserForm1.Show
        Mytext = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
    End If

End Function
```

Both are in the sane WorkBook.
MsgBox(MyPrompt) returns empty .
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Classic Case of why you should be using `Option explicit`

Do you see any difference? ;)

`Public Function PopMessage(ByVal Mypromt As String) As String`

`MsgBox (MyPrompt)`

[INTERESTING READ (Point 2)](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/)

This explains exactly the same problem that you are facing.

Comment: OK, got it now ! I was looking for something more difficult, as often. This error was the occasion to learn more about the art of debugging. Now Option Explicit will be my FIRST line of code !

Comment: Besides `OPTION EXPLICIT`, also avoid using the `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` (OERN) statement which basically means "I don't care about what error comes up in my code, just execute the next line". Sometimes it is not possible to avoid the OERN statement. In such cases, limit its scope to least number of lines possible, by adding the statement ON ERROR GOTO 0, from the line where you want to end the OERN effect.

Answer (score 0):

Um....a typo can cause you a headache

I agree that it is a good habit to always declare variables